# deploying problem with multiple html files. Parcel

Tags: html, npm, path, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

when I deploy a website( with multiple entry points, many HTML files ) and the host uses the build command: `parcel build index.html aboutme.html`. the website deployed give me a 404 error. But if I write in the URL /aboutme.html or /index.html it goes... it's like a routeing problem.

HTTP://localhost:1234 => 404 error,
HTTP://localhost:1234/aboutme.html => it goes.

**with 1 entry point, it goes all right, but I want multiple HTML files.**

I've searched online commands like:

```
"build:client": "parcel build client/index.html --out-dir dist/client",
```

or

```
 "build:server": "parcel build server/index.js --target node --out-dir dist/server",
```

or even more with this weird flag command: `--watch`

Comment: I also have been struggling with how to configure parcel with multiple .html pages; so I put a bounty on this question.  Thank you to anyone for any pointers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

all you need to do for client part:

```
npx parcel build ./*.html
```

that will put result to ./dist directory

if you want now to serve the result on parcel dev server then do:

```
npx parcel ./*.html
```

the both urls will work

http://localhost:1234/ - will open you index

http://localhost:1234/aboutme.html - will open you 'about me'

And - if you modify index.html (in root dir, not in dist) - changes will be automatically pulled to your browser.

Comment: I used build ./*.html and then i did,   "parcel ./*.html --https " With this aobutMe works with Full URL. HOwever, Root https://localhost:1234/ , does not server index.html automatically. I have to explicitly type is https://localhost:1234/index/html . Any way to make root open index HTML automatically?

Comment: I had my files in a "src" folder, so I needed `./src/*.html`