# Parcel - not loading index.html at root

Tags: parceljs

Referring documentation here. https://parceljs.org/features/cli/

We have two HTML files. We did `parcel index.html b.html --https`

URLs when typed explicitly, https://localhost:1234/index.html and https://localhost:1234/b.html  works fine.

However, we were expecting  https://localhost:1234 to serve index.html and we get. "This localhost page cant be found"

Both HTMLs are at the root of the project.

Comment: there is solution discussed here. HOwever, seems it does not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69029045/deploying-problem-with-multiple-html-files-parcel